# pywinauto:saving text to a variable

Tags: pywinauto

I am automating a windows application using pywinauto.
Thanks to Stack Overflow for helping me all the way.

My problem statement goes like this: After a successful run of the code for 10 times (say), I get a success message 10 times which should be captured and placed in excel sheet for each run (using, openpyxl). So I would like to capture the text into an array element.

Is there a way to copy a text to a variable element in pywinauto?

Comment: Copy from where? What do you mean saying `variable element`?

Comment: The text would be displayed in an uneditable form (say,"Transaction is Succesfull").This text to be copied into an array ,so that I can display this message in each cell in an excel .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uneditable form means `disabled edit box / read-only text label` or `non-detectable control without native handle`?

1. For disabled edit box or text label you can get text by using something like that: `app.WindowName.EditBox.WindowText()`. Of course, `EditBox` is a correct access name that can be found in `app.WindowName.PrintControlIdentifiers()` method output.
2. For the non-detectable control you are not able to copy text. Probably future pywinauto 0.6.0 release may help you.